# What is this solid white glue

Tags: identification, glue

[image]

It's rock solid, not like the cables glue.
What is it ?
What is it for ?
How do I remove it ?
How do I put it back ?

Comment: You accepted the answer too quickly (which is probably 100% wrong). Wait a day or two, and you should get real answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "glue block" from PCB?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9377/how-to-remove-glue-block-from-pcb)

Answer (score 14):

This is known as "Potting."

From [pottingsolutions](http://www.pottingsolutions.com/my%20site/Technology/overview_of_potting.htm):

> Potting (embedment) is the covering of an electronic or electrical
>   device to protect it from the surrounding environment.  Most of the
>   time it is for protection from water or moisture and /or to
>   electrically insulate it so that it will operate as designed. This can
>   be done by several methods: potting, casting and encapsulation.  Many
>   names have been used interchangeably so there is some confusion of the
>   terms. The most commonly used term is encapsulation or potting.

I have removed it in the past from a PFC module by scraping it slowly out with a screwdriver.  This is normally only done to figure out what is in the module, or to determine a failing component.  I have never attempted to reverse the procedure, but I assume it would be possible if damage is not done to the components during removal.

Potting Solutions also discusses the removal of the potting:

> There are two ways to  remove potting compound either physically or
>   chemically remove it. To physically remove the potting compound it is
>   common to heat the part until the potting compound becomes soft and it
>   can be torn off.  If it is a high Tg potting compound it could be
>   cooled and then hit to shatter the resin since it is brittle at low
>   (-40C) temperatures.  Chemical removal of the  potting compound is
>   done by soaking in solvents to soften the resin so it can be torn off.
>   The solvents are toxic so care must be used.

Comment: I tried the hot air gun but it's not localized as was said, there's no way it can avoid components (a capacitor exploded) and it's only effective at maximum heat (600°C). I tried drilling, it makes a lot of dust and you don't see what you drill. I tried hammering but it breaks the board with it. I tried a soldering iron but it's too much work, maybe with a large tip. I don't have liquid nitrogen at home and I bet that would break everything with it. So I want to try the chemical way, what solvents must I use ?

Answer (score 0):

boil it in water for 10-15 mins then scrape it off with a screwdriver or spudger

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Your answer needs to contain some explanations rather than just firing off the solution exam-style. It should be written clearly enough to teach future readers. Please can you edit it and greatly improve it. Thanks.